# Flutter - Clipping Path curve is very sharp

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHeXI.png) with a custom clip path.

This is what I get with my
[implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgMzX.png), should I use an arc or a quadratic Bezier  to get this curvature ?

My custom clip path:

```
class EventClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double radius = 30;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width / 2, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width - radius, 0)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, radius),
          radius: Radius.elliptical(40, 20))
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - radius)
      ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - radius, size.height),
          radius: Radius.circular(radius))
      ..lineTo(size.width / 3, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          size.width / 4, size.height, 40, (size.height / 2) - 20)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(40, (size.height / 2) - 20, size.width / 2, 0)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: can you post an image of what you are getting ?

Comment: it's this https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgMzX.png

Answer (score 0):

Not the same as your goal, but try this.

```
Path path = Path()
  ..moveTo(size.width / 1.5, 0)
  ..lineTo(size.width - radius, 0)
  ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
  ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - radius)
  ..arcToPoint(Offset(size.width - radius, size.height), radius: Radius.circular(radius))
  ..lineTo(size.width / 3, size.height)
  ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, size.height, 40, (size.height / 2))
  ..quadraticBezierTo(40, (size.height / 2) - 30, size.width / 2, 0)
  ..close();
```